# Why wont the terminal show me the values for x and y even though ive set them

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and i just cant figure out what the problem is tbh...

```
import random
import itertools
def playagain():
        playagain = input('Would you like to play again? Write YES or NO: ')
        if playagain == 'yes':game()
        elif playagain == 'no':
            print('Ok, Bye!!')
        else:    
            print('So you dumbass really cannot even follow simple instructions huh')
def game():
    import random
import itertools
x = random.randint(1,100)
y = random.randint(1,200)
if x == y:
    itertools.repeat(1)
guessTrials = 3
secret_num = x + y
playgame = input('Would you like to play an addition game? Write yes or no: ')
if playgame == 'yes':game()
elif playgame == 'no':
    print('Ok, Bye!!')
else:    
    print('why u gotta try me like that man')
while guessTrials >= 1:
        try:
            guess = int(input('add these numbers '),print(x,y))
        except ValueError:
            print('Thats not a whole number!')
        else:
            if guess < secret_num:
                print('TOO LOW')

            elif guess > secret_num:
                print('TOO HIGH')
            if guess == secret_num:
                print('You got it mate!')
                playagain()
                
            else:
                guessTrials -= 1
                print('Thats not it. You have {} tries left'.format(guessTrials))

            if guessTrials == 0:
                    print('My number was {}'.format(secret_num))
game()
```

Ive tried switching the position of ,print(x,y)) in line 27 to line 25 which works fine but only once...

Comment: You seem to have some indentation issues. Those are a problem for Python.

Comment: Do you understand that `print` returns `None`? `guess = int(input('add these numbers '),print(x,y))` is almost certainly not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
guess = int(input('add these numbers '),print(x,y))
```

with:

```
guess = int(input('add these numbers: ' + str(x) + ' and ' + str(y)))
```

I'm guessing that what you tried to do, was to add the values of `x` and `y` to the input message using the `print()` function, but that's not how print works - with `print()` you can print things to the console output. The simplest way to add values to a string (like here, adding those values to `add these numbers`) is to use the `+` sign - just make sure that all the elements that you are adding are strings.

To make it cleaner you could use fstrings, like so:

```
guess = int(input(f'add these numbers: {x} and {y}: '))
```

Comment: If that is actually the solution, you can also use f-strings. `print(f"add these numbers: {x} and {y}")`